# Multiple ajax calls with single fail callback

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two arrays with deferreds, to see if outer `when` or inner `when` failed I need to use double `fail` callback aplaying. Is there any way to populate error from inner `when` and use single `fail`?

```
 $.when.apply(null, array1).done(function () {
            $.when.apply(null, array2).done(function () {
                alert("all done, yupi");
            }).fail(failCallback);
        }).fail(failCallback);
```

Comment: Can't you just `concat` the two arrays and check when both arrays are done?

Comment: no because inner array is constructed when outher <code>when</code> is done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how it would be done using ES6 promises

```
Promise.all(array1).then(function() {
    return Promise.all(array2);
}.then(function () {
    alert("all done, yupi");
}.catch(failCallback);
```

So, I assume jQuery would be done like

```
$.when.apply(null, array1).then(function () {
    return $.when.apply(null, array2);
}.then(function () {
    alert("all done, yupi");
}).fail(failCallback);
```